# iOS 4.2+ webfont (ttf) 's bold font-weight rendering bug

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, css, mobile-safari

This one is quite specify: specify ttf font rendering `font-weight:bold` incorrectly on iOS mobile safari, open demo site with iphone/ipad with iOS 4.2/4.3 Beta 3 or above:

(this is Reenie+Beanie from google fonts)

http://jsbin.com/ojeqe3/16/

[Screen capture](http://img.ly/images/730341/full)

You see the bold font look **double rendered**. This is not significant for small and medium font size, but quite significant for large font-size / zoom in

My friend will report this bug to apple. However, anything he can do to solve the bug? (kill the text-adjust **is not** OK)

Update:
This one is **not fixed** in iOS5.

The best solution I know for the problem will be

1. Use `font-weight:normal` (as shown in demo)
2. Use either `-webkit-text-strok`e or `text-shadow` to make it look "bold" (plus iPad only css - body prefix added by js, not only media query)

Comment: Well...if it's a bug then it's a matter of hacking around to see if you can trip a switch somewhere that stops this from triggering - I'd probably try combinations of -webkit text effects to see if I get lucky (like font-smoothing, text-shadow with a transparent shadow, a -webkit text stroke etc.)

Comment: Luckily this is not so significant if you doesn't use the medium font-size and disable zooming...thank you for hint :)

Comment: +1 good question. Same issue. I'm surprised there aren't more votes.

Comment: this problem is actually most prominent when you apply `text-shadow` with a spread that seeps around all corners of the letters.

Comment: This is not fixed as of the date of this comment. It's been years. Apple has really fallen off. I see have less problems with IE 10 than I do with Safari. WTF.

Comment: @pathfinder "Mobile Safari is the new IE6", and all of us know the Mobile Safari on iOS 7 is the worst Safari ever since.

Answer (score 35):

Had the same issue with an `h1` inheriting the `font-weight: bold;` from a parent class. Just overwrite the inherited style with a `font-weight: normal;`

Comment: totally fixed the double render for me.

Comment: It is not the correct answer or the fix - although it stops the double rendering it also stops the ability have bold text with font-face. The user wants to have bold text with font face without this hacky double rendering.

Comment: this fixed the problem for me, but only because I didn't need multiple weights of the font. it would be nice if there was a solution to allow for font-weight:bold to work. I guess we'll just have to wait for the bug to be fixed...

Comment: This just saved me, thank you! Note to those trying to add more font weight to their already custom font-face: choose a font that has the thickness you are looking for, dont hack up someone else's font because you chose wrong - its not going to work everywhere how you imagine it. Choose again.

Comment: This is NOT the correct answer. Please look at Gerry Straahof and Spoike's answers below. They are correct.

Comment: This may fix the problem in this one specific instance, but doesn't explain any of the reasons it occurs or any variations etc – and is pretty much useless as far as helping others in the future. see @Spoike 's answer. It is very clear and concise.

Answer (score 30):

It seems that Mobile Safari has a buggy way of rendering [**faux styles** with font-faces](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/10449/weird-mobile-safari-font-face-problem-font-doubled-and-offset-to-the-left-/p1). For bold it will double the text and offset, and with most fonts it would go unnoticed, but with thin font faces it will look like double vision.

In your case the [Reenie Beanie](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Reenie+Beanie) does **not include a bold style**, and if you're using them as heading without changing the `font-weight` to `normal` or `400` it will render the bold weight "faux styled".

Please do note that using faux styles is generally [buggy in some browsers](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/11/avoiding-faux-weights-styles-google-web-fonts/) and not only in Mobile Safari.

### Solution 1. Use the appropriate `font-weight`

So the best solution is to change the font-weight to the one that Google Fonts provide, quick fix below:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, strong, b { 
    font-weight: 400; 
} 
/* or font-weight: normal */
```

### Solution 2. Use a font that does provide the bold/italic style that you want

The other solution is to pick a font from a web font archive that **does** include a bold style. Alternatives in Google Fonts that look a lot like Reenie Beanie and are "bolder" would be e.g. [Gochi Hand](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Gochi+Hand), [Sunshiney](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Sunshiney), or [Permanent Marker](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Permanent+Marker).

### Solution 3. Fake the faux using other means

If you really insist on wanting a faux bold style you can try using a thin [text-shadow](http://caniuse.com/css-textshadow) or [text stroke](http://caniuse.com/text-stroke).

Comment: This is the correct answer people.  Thanks, Spoike.  Vote this answer up to help others.

Comment: Yup this is the correct answer! Would be nice of @vincicat to accept this answer.

Comment: This is the answer. Being angry at safari for not knowing how to "fake" a bold weight from a font without a supplied bold weight, it silly. @vincicat - you should accept this answer and save future visitors the time.

Comment: Not only did this solve my whacky double font issue that I was confused about, it explained why the font was being rendered that way and taught a different way of thinking about it. We take for granted that we can fake a thicker font sometimes even when we don't have a 700 weight. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 8):

don't use the 'bolder' or 'bold' tag. they aren't necessary if you are using a specific weighted webfont.

I had the same problem. It went away when I removed any mention of font-weight.

Comment: This is the correct answer!  iPad 2 has problems converting normal-weight webfonts into "fake" bold. If you try to make a normal-weight into a bold weight (known as a “fake bold”), then the iPad 2 has a “double rendering” bug where it renders the font at the left-most and right-most boundaries of what would be a bold font, but it does not fill in the space in-between. So it gives the illusion of the font being rendered twice.

Comment: Correct answer! I had 'font-family: custom-bold' to <strong> but in Divi it takes 'font-weight: 700' by default. So I added 'font-weight :normal' and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Try applying this css rule:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Comment: fixed a weird thick rendering issue i had with a font face rule

Comment: The solution is to use a bold font.  iPad 2 has problems converting normal-weight webfonts into fake bold fonts.  See Gerry Straathof and Spoike's answers below.