# @font-face rendering correctly in IE and Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit, font-face

My custom font used to look perfect in all browsers, but after a recent webkit update, it now renders very bold in Chrome and Safari, but looks fine in Firefox and IE.

Here is my CSS:

```
@font-face  {
    font-family: "KlavikaBasicRegular";
    src: url("i/klavikabasic-regular-webfont.eot");
    src: url("i/klavikabasic-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("i/klavikabasic-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("i/klavikabasic-regular-webfont.otf") format("opentype"),
         url("i/klavikabasic-regular-webfont.svg#KlavikaBasicRegular") format("svg");
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
}
.block_header {
    font-family:"KlavikaBasicRegular",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #5b5b5b;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px 10px 5px 20px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<h3 class="block_header">MY headline</h3>
```

[image: Font-face-firefox-chrome]

Anybody else notice a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I personally have not...

I would say that you are most likely correct and that there are differences in render of various browsers..

I see you already have the `weight:normal`...

Try `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`

See @ http://ilikekillnerds.com/2010/12/a-solution-to-stop-font-face-fonts-looking-bold-on-mac-browsers/

Comment: Thanks, but that had no effect.

Comment: Try a smaller font size or using text shadow...  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069752/ios-4-2-webfont-ttf-s-bold-font-weight-rendering-bug

Comment: Font-size is irrelevant. The problem exists no matter the size. I've tried all sizes from 12px up to 30px.

Comment: What about shadow could you force it to have a shadow which is the same bg color of your page and use the shadow to slim the characters down?

Comment: That was an interesting idea but it didn't affect the boldness. Still too bold. And I'm on Windows, not Mac.

Comment: Says here the order of the properties may be important :P http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/10533/text-smoothing/p1

Comment: Also try `font-style:normal` or bold or italics and then override the look at the local element with another style ? lol I am leaving this one alone :P

Comment: Last but not least please DO report your issue to the appropriate browser developer with example should you find no solution... Sometimes we need a reaming to see the light :P

Comment: Author of the blog post here. I've noticed the issue is sometimes caused by the colour of the text and the background colour. White text on a black background is a repeat offender I've noticed and very susceptible to font face issues. It's a weird issue, sometimes the font smoothing fix works, but sometimes it's something more than the property can fix.