# Double header on iphone

Tags: iphone, html, css

I have come across a weird double header/h1 tag on the iPhone 4. If you view the my site on an iPhone the header is rendered twice, but overlaying each other slightly, if you zoom in on the header, it becomes one, like a normal heading on any website.

Has anyone else encountered this and know a solution? I've been at it for weeks can't find anything like it online.

Here is my site: http://cafe.cic.hull.ac.uk/~405851/

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does it only do that when you use that custom font? What if you use no font or a different font? I have a hunch this is a rendering bug in iOS6 related to custom fonts somehow.

Comment: I did remove the custom font, and the default font-family was working normally, I'm beginning to think this is a iOS bug too. I've just done some more researching online and there's been other issues with custom fonts since iOS5.

Comment: Also this issue is present in Google Chrome on the iPhone. So I assume iOS bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems similar to the one discussed and answered here: [iOS 4.2+ webfont (ttf) 's bold font-weight rendering bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069752/ios-4-2-webfont-ttf-s-bold-font-weight-rendering-bug)

Apparently one solution is to to change the inherited style via a font-weight:normal styling.  This doesn't solve your issue if you feel that the text needs to be bold of course.  You could try using different font weights as well.

Comment: Tried changing the font-weight didn't fix it, the font doesn't change, because it'sa custom font using `@font-face`

Comment: Thanks, it turns out last time I was changing the font-weight, I did something wrong, setting h1 tag to `font-weight:normal` did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Custom font rendering has had funky bugs in iOS for a while. In the iOS3 days, I was able to crash webkit itself with custom fonts. Good times.

So I would recommend using something like http://www.google.com/webfonts instead. The font files they serve are guaranteed to work well cross platform, and the stylesheet to include the fonts is tailored to the quirks of platform that requests it. They do a good job at avoiding font rendering bugs and cross platform inconsistencies.

For that reason, I would use Google WebFonts to serve any custom fonts if I had web content that needed to be shown consistently cross platform.

The tradeoff is that you don't get as much selection of fonts. But they do have a good amount, just not *every* font.

Comment: I used one of the fonts from google fonts, and the issue is still there.

Comment: You may have got the `TTF` file from Google, but that doesn't mean you are "using" the service. The way it works is that you let Google serve the stylesheet that declares the font. Google then detects the platform requesting the font and can serve up the font in a format that renders with fewer bugs.

Comment: Nope using the service. It looks like only 'normal' font-style are working, if you use `font-style:italic;` the issue appears.