# Doubled text on iOS5

Tags: css, ios5

I'm working on a responsive site.  After viewing it on a device running iOS5, I notice that all my h2 tags seem to display twice, one on top of the other.  I checked it on a device with iOS6 and it looks better, but not on the iOS5.  However, when I change my h2 tags to spans (changing them to display: inline-block) it seems to work fine as well.

I'm not doing anything seemingly out of the ordinary with my HTML or CSS, and I'm also not using a z-index anywhere in the document so would anyone have an idea what is happening?

```
 <h2>Hello</h2>


 h2 {
display: block;
font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
font-size: 36px;
color: #C41230;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: http://i1242.photobucket.com/albums/gg539/ndecesa/photo.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your problem could be a font weight rendering bug. It might be inheriting bold styling. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069752/ios-4-2-webfont-ttf-s-bold-font-weight-rendering-bug). You could try setting your font weight to normal for `h1`, `h2`, etc.