# Why is iOS Safari adding extra letter-spacing?

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I think I have found a web rendering bug for Google Fonts in Mobile (iOS 8) Safari. It seems to me that Mobile Safari adds a tiny bit of letter-spacing to all text that uses Google Fonts, or that it uses another font. It doesn't matter which Google Font I try (Open Sans). It renders correctly on all modern browsers. Tested Android, FF, Chrome, Safari.

Try to load this page on a iOS device to see what I mean. See also see code and screenshot. See this link for live review: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/430406/Temp%20%5Bok%20to%20delete%5D/Checking%20Font/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 style="font-family: 'Roboto'">Roboto: Looks like it gets a bit extra line-spacing in iOS Safari, though this is not possible to find in web inspector</h2>
  <h2 style="font-family: 'Arial'">Arial: Works fine in iOS Safari</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I think you have answered your own question, "Muli" is not a web safe font, therefor you can expect unexpected behavior in some browsers which is what you are experiencing. Use a different font, preferably a web safe font for consistency among browsers. Its a best practice.

Comment: FYI, I didn't down vote, who ever did, at least provide an explanation as to why you down voted. That isn't promoting better questions/answers in SO.

Comment: iOS Safari should support Google Fonts, and it renders correctly in all other modern browsers, so using a "web safe" font is not an alternative. There must be another solution. Here is a simpler example of the problem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/430406/Temp%20%5Bok%20to%20delete%5D/Checking%20Font/index.html

Comment: @Andreas Did you use any letter-spacing rule on the example above (screenshots)?

Comment: @sdcr No I did not. See the dropbox-link in my comment, for a simpler solution. Check out the code.

Comment: @Andreas that dropbox link does not work, it ignores non-secure content.

Comment: i'm just here for the 4:20 blazers.

Answer (score 76):

I found the solution in this question: [iOS 4.2+ webfont (ttf) 's bold font-weight rendering bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069752/ios-4-2-webfont-ttf-s-bold-font-weight-rendering-bug/11879044#11879044)

Mobile Safari is buggy rendering faux font weights, if you don't set the font-weight (to eg. `font-weight: 400` or `font-weight: normal`) You need to specifically set the css font weight for it to render correctly in mobile safari.

This is the solution.

```css
h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: I'd give you 1000 upvotes if I could. Just wasted 3 hours on this problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue: I was setting the weight but wasn't actually loading in the weight for that font.

Comment: Crazy. Thanks so much for this!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you have this bug using variable fonts, don't forget to define your `font-weight` as a range. for example: `font-weight: 200 1000;`

Answer (score 19):

Note that Google Web Fonts only exports the regular weight (400) by default, which can lead to Mobile Safari (and other browsers) being forced to impose faux bold.

To explicitly export bolder weights, select "CUSTOMISE" in the Google Web Font font selection pane, manually check each additional weight you require, and use the updated embed code.

[[image: ([Screenshot: Google Fonts customise pane])](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxykp.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxykp.png)

Comment: Fixed my problem, didn't realise browsers applied a faux bold without the proper font file(s)

Comment: I found that you need to use the exact matching font weight as what you've loaded. In my case, I was using a medium weight (500) for my bold styles, but setting font-weight to 600, and that was causing iOS to add the extra letter-spacing. Once I started using the 600 weight font, the letter-spacing bug went away.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a similar problem which I resolved. I'm using the **Lato** font family from Google Fonts and Safari was adding letter spacing even when explicitly using `font-weight: 600`.

I imported only the font weights 400, 500 & 600, as these were the only weights I was using. After many hours I just decided to try also importing font weight 700 and this fixed my issue... Safari was no longer adding letter spacing when using `font-weight: 600`!

So even though I explicitly use `font-weight: 600`, Safari seemed to need the 700 variant as well to render the 600-weighted font properly. Very odd.

Comment: Happened to me just now with Vohlkov as well. Thaks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

Need to specify font-weight

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Din';
    src: url('./DinRoundRegular.otf');
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
    font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Din';
    src: url('./DINRoundPro-Medi.ttf');
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: bold;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```