# Large letter-spacing only on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, text, fonts

To my surprise the letter-spacing is not working in mobile browsers, Android and iOS. Desktop Work Fine. Very big letter-spacing, how i can fix it?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typically i would build the site starting with bootstrap and that should prevent those issues usually. Short of that, i would use one of a two solutions.

The first is to simply use seperate styling sheets for the site depending on the screen size.
`<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" href="800.css" />`

with the css having the "letter-spacing" attribute set to whatever you wanted. for example:

```
p {  
  letter-spacing:3px;
  color;#000000;
  font-family:sarif;
}
```

The second option is to use jquery to adjust the letter spacing directly

```
if (window.width() <= 800) { 
  $("p").css("letter-spacing", "3px");
});
```

This is the most elegant of the solutions, but if you aren't well versed enough in jquery, then the first solution should work fine, though it is not recommended.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not right solution. I use Roboto font, on desktop is fine, but on mobile letter-spacing is big. Responsive test does not reveal problems, only on mobile browser.

Comment: I think i may have found the issue, possibly. If you are using mobile safari then you should try setting the font-weight to "font-weight: default;" It might be the issue on other browsers if it is having trouble rendering the font-weight. [where i found this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28833958/why-is-ios-safari-adding-extra-letter-spacing)