# Safari weird font bug when using font-weight

Tags: css, fonts, safari

From the images below, you can see that the font rendering used by safari adds some white lines to some characters. This occurs in Safari for both iOS and Mac. While in the example below it is not as noticeable, in practice it can be quite distracting.

[image: Full text]
[image: Close up]

I noticed this happened after I added `font-weight: 400;` to my text. The reason I added it was to fix another issue by Safari which rendered by font with large kerning between letters see [this Stack Overlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28833958/why-is-ios-safari-adding-extra-letter-spacing).

This is the entire CSS for the text:

```
h2 {
  font-family: 'My-Font', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Is this another bug in Safari and is there a workaround if so? Thanks.

Comment: looks like anti-aliassing, have you tried setting the [text-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering) property, possibly in conjunction with [font-smoothing](https://www.mobomo.com/2014/05/better-font-smoothing-in-chrome-on-mac-os-x/)?

Answer (score 1):

Some folks recommend

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

Other

```
transform: perspective(1px);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have lost countless hours trying to fix a weird font rendering issue in Safari (text was being cut off on the right-hand side, no matter what I tried)... Finally bumped into this question (after many others) - the 'transform: perspective(1px)' made it go away.